# How do I activate a counter?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I'm trying to build an electronic lock that takes a 4 digit password and if the password is inserted wrong three times in a row, a logic display is activated.
Below is the lock, it works fine, but I can't figure out how to activate the counter that counts the number of times the password is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: The first obvious problem is that you have no "unlock" push-button to determine when to count a password attempt. How were you planning on tackling that?

Comment: if none of the codes start with binary 0000 you can or together lines bus lines 1,2,3,4 to determine that 4 digits have been entered

Comment: Since you need a pass/fail indication and you cannot trust the output of your 4th digit's (A=B) until you know there have been 4 entered digits, you need to solve that first. Then you can use (A=B). For this, you'll need a binary counter and a D flop to latch the (A=B) when the D triggers on bit2 of the counter. All this is before you work out the three-tries problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDIx57.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are two '161 counters. One that counts up to 4. Another that counts up to 3.

I assume that the PB input is a push-button that is momentarily HIGH and then returns to LOW when released. So PB is *active HIGH*. The RESET input should be kept HIGH when not in use. It is *active LOW*. You can see the addition of a D-flop with a /CLR. This latches the status and the output of the '74 will be HIGH if the code matches. If not, up to three tries will be allowed. After which, no more will be allowed until the RESET is cycled.

Answer (score 1):

put a counter on the clock line connect the reset to `A=B` on the fourth 74LS86 and connect the "too-many" output inverted to `IA=B` on the first 74LS86

I'm guessing twelve button presses counts as three tries, even though 12 presses presses has tested 13 different codes (including 0000) that is unless you're using excess three coding (or some other symbology that excludes the reset state)

if you're using excess three you can or-together lines 1,2,3,4 to detect when 4 digits have been entered and possibly use that in combination with the lock  output to perform a reset of the shift registers if the code is wrong - thus allowing only a single guess per 4 digits.

Comment: I get the part of connecting the reset to`A=B`, but what do you mean with the "too-many" output?

Comment: what do you mean by three tries?

Comment: 3 tries is 12 button presses, as you said

Comment: so have the counter count to 12 and after and then have it block perhaps by gating the clock line from the keyboard.  eg pre-load a 74LS163 with 4 and on the 12th pulse `RCO` will go high.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @transistor, you will need a way to generate a pulse on a failed attempt. Here is a schematic to accomplish that. Its cheap and easy to build. You could use a hidden reed relay connected to the reset line, and run a magnet past it, Or use a 555 timer that will reset it after X ammount of time.
Just a thought[image]

Comment: In case its hard to read that is a CD4017 COUNTER CHIP, DEPENDING ON THE OUTPUT PIN USED YOU COULD CHANGE THE # OF TRY'S UP TO 10

Comment: What I meant was if you figure a way to get a pulse per failed try, you could use this as a 4th or more pulse lock out circuit.